# Insertar formulario por AJAX, que haga un redirect con el succes

Tags: laravel, ajax

estoy insertando un formulario con AJAX en Laravel, pero quiero que cuando se inserte haga un redirect a productos, y con el `with` para mandar el mensaje de producto insertado, pero no se como hacerlo.

```
$("#guardamos").click(() => {
        var selects = $(".variaciones").toArray();
        var tipos = selects.map((item) => {
        return { id: $(item).attr("id"), variaciones: $(item).val() || [] };
        });
        //console.log(tipos);
        // Generamos las permutaciones
        var array = obtenerCombinaciones(tipos);
        var producto = $('#nombre').val();
        var ed = tinyMCE.get('descripcion');
        var descripcion = ed.getContent();
        var categoria = $('#categoriaEle').val();
        var proveedor = $('#proveedor').val();
        var referencia = $('#referencia').val();
        var subcategoria = $('input:radio[name=subcategoria]:checked').val();
        var foto = $('#thumbnail2').val();
        var idProducto = $('#respuesta').val();

        var url = 'add-producto/insertando';
        $.ajax({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: {'array': JSON.stringify(array), 
                   'Producto': producto,
                   'Descripcion': descripcion,
                   'ID': idProducto,
                   'Categoria': categoria,
                   'Proveedor': proveedor,
                   'Referencia': referencia,
                   'Subcategoria': subcategoria,
                   'Foto': foto },     
            success: function(data){
                window.location = "/productos";
            },
         });
        console.log(array);
    });
```

En el controlador hago el redirect, pero claro me manda la respuesta al success del AJAX, y quiero redirigir y que sala el mensajito como cuando haces submit con el formulario.

```
return redirect("productos")->with('info', 'Producto añadido correctamente!');
```

Comment: La idea de usar AJAX es evitar recargar la página, lo ideal sería que agregues el nuevo producto a tu lista (o tabla), así no tendrás problema para mostrar el mensaje y mejoras la experiencia del usuario.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que haría sería primero mostrar el mensaje que me da el success y luego redireccionar con `window.location`. Por ejemplo:

```
$.toast({
    heading: 'PRODUCTO',
    text: data,
    position: 'right',
    loaderBg: '#ff6849',
    icon: 'info',
    hideAfter: hideAfter,
    stack: 6,
});

window.location.href = window.location.origin + '/productos';
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad @Stack News . De este modo que me indicas si me redirige pero no obtengo el mensaje